# Duvida Sobre Eclipse

Tags: spring-tools-suite

tudo bem? Eu fiquei um tempo sem usar meu STS (Spring Tools Suits) e agora tem esse "Default Package" e não encontrei como tirar ele, alguém já teve esse problema? [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se não me engano, ele é a pasta raiz do projeto.

Comment: sim, porem eu me recordo que antigamente ela não aparecia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clique na seta que esta no canto superior da janela "package explorer" e clique na opção "1 Empty parent packages".

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142470/eclipsedefault-package-always-visible

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo aqui!